# Python Mysql Query Cache and use it later for join

Tags: python, mysql, query-cache

I have 3 tables A, B and C. Among three tables 2 tables(A, B) are won't change frequently. but C changes frequently.

Now, i want to write a python programming to display all fields in 3 tables.

Here my problem is that A and B have huge data. Can i cache A join B data and use it for late to join with C?

if possible how can I ? can u explain with some python snippet ?

Comment: can you not just implement *write-through-cache* mechanism? Say `redis` or `hazelcast` on top of your db?

Answer (score 0):

you can make a query cache with `mysql.connector`

```
import mysql.connector
con = mysql.connector.Connect(host='XXX', port=XXX, user='XXX',     password='XXX', database='XXX')
cur = con.cursor()
db = cur.execute("""select SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE * from abc""")
data = cur.fetchall()
print (data)
```

if you want to update the query result, use `cur.commit()`

Comment: sorry for not knowing may be but here `abc` is?

Comment: just a simple example, you can perform any query you like, and it will be cached if u didn't use cur.commit()